# Trying to get a blur effect over video on scroll

Tags: javascript

I found a great little script that blurs background images on scroll. Was hoping I could get it to work over a background video. And it *sort of* does. But it seems to work backwards in a way. The video loads correctly at first. When you start to scroll, it instantly goes away, then starts to fade back IN instead of OUT. Not sure how, or if, I can make it work properly. Seems to be fine on a background image. But not on a video.

```js
(function() {
        'user strict';
        var hello = document.getElementById('homeheadline'),
            blur = document.getElementById('video'),
            windowHeight = window.innerHeight,
            isScroll = false;

        var latestScroll = 0;
        var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

        window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;

        var init = function() {
            window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
                latestScroll = window.scrollY;
                checkScroll();
            }, false);
        }

        var checkScroll = function() {
            if(!isScroll) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
            }
            isScroll = true;
        }

        var update = function() {
            currentScroll = latestScroll;
            isScroll = false;
            var helloScroll = currentScroll / 4,
                blurScroll = currentScroll * 2;

            hello.style.transform = 'translate3d(0, ' + helloScroll + 'px, 0)';
            blur.style.opacity = (blurScroll / windowHeight - .1).toFixed(2);
            if(blur.style.opacity >= 1) {
                blur.style.opacity = 1;
            }
        }

        init();
    })();
```

```css
.jumbotron {
    min-height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.jumbotron .video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
    object-fit: cover;
    opacity: 1;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    video {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}

.jumbotron .container-fluid {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    .jumbotron .container-fluid {
        z-index: 2;
        position: relative;
        top: 40%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
}

.jumbotron .alternate {
    background-color: rgba(50,88,125,.4) !important;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
    margin: 20rem 0 15rem;
}

.jumbotron .alternate h1 {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.jumbotron .alternate h1:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 4px;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: https://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#32587d+0,b5c1af+33,c88362+66,e0c094+100 */
    background: rgb(50,88,125); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(50,88,125,1) 0%, rgba(181,193,175,1) 33%, rgba(200,131,98,1) 66%, rgba(224,192,148,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(50,88,125,1) 0%,rgba(181,193,175,1) 33%,rgba(200,131,98,1) 66%,rgba(224,192,148,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(50,88,125,1) 0%,rgba(181,193,175,1) 33%,rgba(200,131,98,1) 66%,rgba(224,192,148,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#32587d', endColorstr='#e0c094',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

.jumbotron .alternate p {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="video-container">
      <video id="video" playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop" autoplay loop>
        <source src="https://www.thepixelpixie.com/px-c0nt3n5/uploads/2021/07/Vienna-13394.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid hero-text d-flex align-items-center">
      <!--<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <h1>Meet Us<br />at the Mall.</h1>
                        <p>We're redefining what the mall means to our communities by adding in-demand retail, dining, entertainment, and other mixed-uses. See what else is in store. Meet us at the mall.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>-->
      <div id="homeheadline" class="row alternate w-100 justify-content-center homeheadline">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-8 col-lg-6">
          <h1 class="w-100 text-center font-effect-destruction">Headline 1</h1>
          <p class="w-100 text-center font-effect-destruction">Some text describing the headline</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section class="about">
    <p>original pen/script created by <a href="http://harayu.com">harayu</a></p>
    <p>Laura Sage is trying to make it work over a video</p>
  </section>
```

Comment: What is the end result you are wanting to achieve? That the video starts visible and fades as you scroll down? Or the video starts invisible and fades in as you scroll down?

Comment: Video starts visible and fades as you scroll down. Here's a link to the original script: https://github.com/harayu/Blur-effect-on-scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the linked source works is there are two images, one which is blurred and one which is not. The blurred one is overlaid over the non-blurred one, but it starts out with no opacity. As you scroll the page it becomes more opaque, making it look like the original image was blurring.

The HTML code you've linked only has one video element, and it starts out fully opaque. So since the JS you adapted from the example is built on the assumptions:

1.) there are two media elements

2.) the blurred element starts with no opacity and becomes more opaque on scroll

You get the behavior you see.

You may want to try mimicking the linked source closer by using two similar videos, one blurred and one non-blurred. I've no idea if that'd achieve the same effect, but, hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Oh wow. I don't know how I didn't even notice the 2nd image. Thank you so much!

Comment: From my experiments, it doesn't look like this can work with video. I'm bummed. But it was worth trying :)